# Why only the return value of the second function call is printed?

Tags: javascript, function, return, function-calls

When I write this code in the console:

```
function lol() {
    var a = 6;
    return a;
}

function test() {
    var a = 8;
    return a;
}

lol();
test();
```

It prints only the return value of the second function call like this:

```
8
```

Why this is happening? Can anyone explain me what happens under the hood?

Comment: where are you trying to print it? if you want to print it on console then console print output of last statement only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console only prints the value of the last statement evaluated. That's just what it does. If you want more, you can explicitly call `console.log( lol() );` or whatever.